# Grunt convert markdown to pdf recursively and dynamically

Tags: gruntjs

I am stuck writing a Gruntfile which aim is to convert a bunch of Markdown files to PDF dynamically. Giving the current folder hierarchy:

```
root/
  |_subfolder1
  |    |_filename1.md
  |_subfolder2
       |_filename2.md
 ...
  |_node_modules
  |_subfolderN
       |filenameN.md
```

I would like to run a Markdown to PDF task which would process the md file and ouput a PDF file with the matching filename in the same output directory.

I did create a custom task which is parsing current directory, ignoring the mode_modules folder and get the markdown file, but I don't know how to configure the md2pdf task with the good properties to reflect dynamic folder mapping.

Here's my current Gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // 1 - Configuration
  grunt.initConfig({
    md2pdf: {
    }
  });

   // 2 - Plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-md2pdf');

  // 3 - Task registering
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'Get Subfolders', function() {

    grunt.file.recurse('.', callback);

    function callback(abspath, rootdir, subdir, filename) {
      var filenameOutExt;

      // if current occurence is a file subdir == undefined
      // checking subdir to true means it's not undefined and
      // the current path is a directory
      if(subdir) {
        // excluding node_modules folder
        if (!subdir.match('node_modules')) {
          // only process markdown files
          if(filename.match('.md')) {
            filenameOutExt = filename.split('.')[0];
            // now for each markdown files, run md2pdf task
            // and ouput filenameOutExt.pdf in same folder
            // as the input files
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
};
```

I am using this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-md2pdf

So my questions is how should I configure the md2pdf task to pass it the markdown files and generate matching filename pdf output in same directory.

Output should be:

```
root/
  |_subfolder1
  |    |_filename1.md
       |_filename1.pdf
  |_subfolder2
       |_filename2.md
       |_filename2.pdf
 ...
  |_node_modules
  |_subfolderN
       |filenameN.md
       |_filenameN.pdf
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you need it to be a grunt task? Is is part of your development workflow? Will you do it often? Maybe you could simply write a node script? :)

Comment: Yes I would like it to be a grunt task. Yes it's part of my development workflow. I think I will do it often. I am currently doing this task to read some books about node, put some notes in markdown files and generate clean formatted PDF using custom CSS :D

Comment: Ok, then... so let's do this. One second.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fdcef10f9f08ed0710ce for a better structured approach of this task :) I think I am close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this line](https://github.com/bgerrissen/grunt-md2pdf/blob/master/tasks/md2pdf.js#L24), this task uses the `grunt.files` utilitary function. This makes things easier for us!

First, it's not usual in grunt to create a different task to find the files you need in any other task.

That is, each task should receive the files it needs to operate on. [For example...](https://github.com/firstdoit/firstdoit.com/blob/39070bb6eff920e7f90d44d4f4c296f0ab483170/Gruntfile.coffee#L6)

```
coffee:
  main:
    files: [
      expand: true
      cwd: 'assets/script'
      src: ['**/*.coffee']
      dest: "assets/script"
      ext: '.js'
    ]
```

(Note that this config is in a Gruntfile.**coffee** file, hence the CoffeeScript syntax)

This type of file configuration using **glob expansion** is one of the most common. You can find [details in the documentation](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files).

It's pretty obvious:

> In every directory (`**`), take everything (`/*`) from `assets/script/` that ends with `.coffee`. Put it into `assets/script`. Rename extensions to `.js`.

So, your task can probably be configured like that:

```
md2pdf: {
  main: {
    files: [ {
      expand: true,
      src: ['**/*.md', '!node_modules/**/*'],
      dest: "pdf/"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That would do the trick and it helped understanding some concept about grunt's file system. However I need to create each PDF file using markdown's filename (book1.md book1.pdf) and in the same folder as the markdown file

Comment: In that case, simply alter dest.

Comment: Yes but how can I variables (folder and filename) in dest using that structure ?

Comment: `dest: './'` will do, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Ok figured it out !

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

 // 2 - Plugins
 grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-md2pdf');

 grunt.registerTask('default', 'Dynamically generate PDF from MD', function() {

   grunt.file.expand("./**/*.md").forEach( function(file) {
     if(!file.match('./node_modules')) {
      var md2pdf = grunt.config.get('md2pdf') || {};
      md2pdf[file] = {
        src: file,
        dest: file + '.pdf'
      };

      grunt.config.set('md2pdf', md2pdf);
    }
  });
  grunt.task.run('md2pdf');
});
};
```